# pycassa - Remove multiple rows by their secondary index?

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

I have a column family with a secondary index 'pointer'. How do I remove multiple rows that have the same 'pointer' value (e.g. abc)?

The only option I know is:

```
expr = create_index_expression('pointer', 'abc')
clause = create_index_clause([expr])
for key, user in cassandra_cf.get_indexed_slices(clause):
    cassandra_cf.remove(key)
```

but I know this is very inefficient and can take long if I have thousands of rows with the same 'pointer' value. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove multiple rows at once:

```
expr = create_index_expression('pointer', 'abc')
clause = create_index_clause([expr])
with cassandra_cf.batch() as b:
    for key, user in cassandra_cf.get_indexed_slices(clause):
        b.remove(key)
```

This will group the removes into batches of 100 (by default).  When the batch object is used as a context manager as it is here, it will automatically handle sending any remaining mutations once the `with` block is left.

You can read more about this in the [`pycassa.batch` API docs](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/api/pycassa/batch.html).